# Como crear múltiples arraylist dentro de un bucle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist

Quiero crear múltiples arraylist dependiendo de la cantidad que traiga de la base de datos.

```
Cursor res = DB.getProcesos(id);

    while(res.moveToNext()){
        ArrayList<String> list+res.getInt(0) = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Quiero ver si hay alguna manera de concatenar la variable list con un dato de la BD y con eso lograr múltiples arraylist dependiendo de cuantos datos traiga.

Answer (score 0):

No logro entender del todo tu pregunta pero si deseas crear varios arrayslist una forma seria usando un vector de arrayslist que seria masomenos asi:

```java
    public static void main(String [] args){
        ArrayList<String> lista[]=new ArrayList[5];
        lista[0]=new ArrayList<String>();
        lista[1]=new ArrayList<String>();
        lista[0].add("hola");
        lista[1].add("persona");
        System.out.println(lista[0].get(0)+" "+lista[1].get(0));
        //output: hola persona
    }
```